# What is the optimal way to delete massive data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanna to delete massive data, like hundreds of thousands of records in ElasticSearch.

There are two ways I have considered, one way is delete in only one [delete_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) request, with `requests_per_second` parameter to control the rate.

Another way is to split into several small requests, via setting `max_docs` and also `requests_per_second`.

I do not know which one is better, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to leverage [slices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-slice) when running update/delete queries.

`slices=auto` works perfectly well and will parallelize the query over all shards of the index being queried. Obviously, if your index has a single shard, it's not going to help. Also, if you index has many shards that are not well balanced, slicing is not going to help either. But in all other cases (i.e. when using the default routing), update/delete queries with slicing run generally faster that without slicing (which by definition would run on a single shard).

Also since those queries generally take a long time, running them asynchronously via `wait_for_completion=false` is better, otherwise you'll get a timeout and won't see the response.